# Rank card on discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to do the rank command which I did but I don't know how to create the card image. I tried to use PIL but as I read it is dead and I have not found anything new. How could I do now? There is no tutorial with discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def rank(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    #Qui definiamo tutte le variabili
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_xp FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(member.id)}")
    user_xp = cursor.fetchall()
    xp = user_xp[0][0]
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(member.id)}")
    user_level = cursor.fetchall()
    lvl = user_level[0][0]
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT xp_level FROM levels WHERE level = {lvl + 1}")
    xp_level = cursor.fetchall()
    next_xp = xp_level[0][0]
    await ctx.send(f"Livello: **{lvl}**\nEsperienza: **{xp}|{next_xp}**")
```

Comment: As an additional note. You shouldn't name your instance or bot "client" because it's actually and instance of class "Bot" so you should probably name it "bot"

Answer (score 0):

PIL was picked up by pillow you can see the tutorial here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html

Also, i just want to point that you shouldn't use f-strings to build sql queries. If you happen to parse an insecure query your whole database could be compromised.

Here's a good explanation from the sqlite3 python driver. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Here's the appropriate xkcd comic to illustrate it.
https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Isn't it possible to have a specific script for what I need?

Comment: Im sorry but who knows what you need, check the link i posted, make something that adapts to your needs!

Comment: Background Image, Discord Profile Image, Progress Bar and nothing more.